# perl sybase connection error on x86pc-solaris

Tags: perl, sybase

I have a Solaris system with x86 CPU, when I try to connect to sybase db with perl, i got the following error(the error was generated when I run the script in debug mode and step into function DBD::Sybase::db::_login at Sybase.pm in line 94)

**ct_con_props(CS_PASSWORD) failed at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DBD/Sybase.pm line 94.
 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DBD/Sybase.pm line 94
        DBD::Sybase::dr::connect('DBI::dr=HASH(0x8613a5c)', 'server=server1', 'user1, 'password1', 'HASH(0x86b4e5c)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DBI.pm line 617
        DBI::_*ANON*_/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DBI.pm:679 called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DBI.pm line 681
        DBI::connect('DBI', 'DBI:Sybase:server=server1', 'user1, 'password1') called at ./test.pl line 28
DBI::CODE(0x83fcdd4)(/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DBI.pm:618):
618:                $user = '' if !defined $user;**

from the message, it seems there is something wrong with the password? but I am sure the password was correct and the same code works very well on a Spark-solaris system, could anyone tell me what's wrong, or tell me how can I get into the function DBD::Sybase::db::_login($this, $server, $user, $auth, $attr)? looks like this function was in an .xs file, but I can not find where is it, and can not debug into it.

if I run the script withtout debug, i got the following error

**ct_con_props(CS_PASSWORD) failed at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris/DBD/Sybase.pm line 94.
DBI connect('server=server1','user1’,...) failed: OpenClient message: LAYER = (1) ORIGIN = (4) SEVERITY = (6) NUMBER = (221)
Server server1, database
Message String: ct__string_extended_encryption: user api layer: internal common library error: error string not available
 at ./test.pl line 28
Connect failed at ./test.pl line 28.**

here is the code of sub connect in Sybase.pm

```
 sub connect {
    my($drh, $dbase, $user, $auth, $attr) = @_;
    my $ifile = '';
    my $server = $dbase || $ENV{DSQUERY} || 'SYBASE';

    my($this) = DBI::_new_dbh($drh, {
        'Name'         => $server,
        'Username'     => $user,
        'CURRENT_USER' => $user,
    });

    DBD::Sybase::db::_login($this, $server, $user, $auth, $attr)
        or return undef;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sending a email to Michael Peppler(the module writer), I got the following answer and the issue was fixed.

The issue is the lib3p directory, which contains libraries that are loaded at run time directly by OpenClient, in particular for things like password encryption, etc.

This directory obviously needs to be in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or be referenced in the default library search paths.

So basically, I need to add the path of OCS-15 folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH